# Download or Move Snowflake Worksheet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

our org is a snowflake customer. Right now we are trying to migrate snowflake user account to our parent company account i.e User@child.com >> user@parent.com. The problem is once we create a parent company account we dont have any option to move the worksheets, dashboards or filters from the child company account. Many of our users have more than 400 worksheets and we dont want to create that manually. Is there is any options to migrate worksheets from one account to another. Sharing is not an option because the child user account will be removed. I found this [snowsightextension](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfsnowsightextensions) resource to export and import the worksheet but it stopped working recently due to snowflake authentication method changes. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: While it's not a direct answer to your question, I'd have to imagine your organization's Snowflake account representative would have some thoughts about how to accomplish this. What did they say when you reached out to them?

Comment: @esqew We dont have options to do that. Snowflake is working on implementing the snowsight extension directly in snowsight UI but dont have an ETA. I pretty sure many of the org would have gone through this issue. Thats why the question is posted.

Comment: Hi - can you explain in more detail what you mean by “due to snowflake authentication method changes”? Given the SnowSight extensions should do what you want, I would focus on resolving this authentication issue before spending time on looking for an alternative solution

Comment: @NickW Snowsight extension uses youraccount.snowflakecomputing.com/session/v1/login-request, Post method to get the authentication token. Lookslike this api no longer works for authentication.

Comment: https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfsnowsightextensions/issues/45#issuecomment-1826883400 states "We are aware of changes to the Snowsight UI that will eventually cause breaking changes to snowsightextensions. In short, snowsightextensions is reaching end of life." I suspect this is a case of WON'T FIX and you will have to reach out to Snowflake support for an alternative solution for worksheet and dashboard migration.

Comment: It has been a while since I explored this, but Snowflake used to store worksheets in your user stage.  You could have your users download those from their stage and then re-upload them to the new account.  As I mention, it has been a while, so not sure that's how it's handled in Snowsight, still.

Comment: @MikeWalton Could you please add more details on this? we can find that in classic console?

Comment: you can see what is in a user's stage by executing `LS @~;` in a worksheet.  I believe you'll find your saved worksheets in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets can be found in a user's stage:

```
LIST @~/worksheet_data;
```

Using snowsql or another connector, you can execute a `GET` command to download those files, and then a `PUT` to push them to the new account location.

Comment: i believe those are classic console worksheets rather than snowsight though

Comment: if you load them in, I believe Snowsight will prompt you to import them, though.  I reiterate my comment from above that....I haven't tried this myself, yet.

Answer (score 0):

there is an option to recover worksheets of a dropped user that may do what you need in a very risky way. Maybe it is possible to drop user manually get their worksheets as tar gz undrop the user

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-worksheets#label-snowsight-worksheets-recover-dropped